# Hive Index Performance

Tags: hive

I have two tables Table A and Table B which are 100GB and 35GB in size respectively. Also both the tables are compact indexed on the same column which is prodID.

I am facing an issue here where I am getting the same response time with or without index for a below query. It takes 30 minute to process the query.

select a.* from TableA a inner join TableB b on a.prodID=b.prodID.

I have 19 nodes cluster setup. Can you please advise me if I am missing any configuration here or doing something wrong.

Regards,
Prabu

Comment: I don't think indices will help much with the join. You should consider defining your input tables clustered by prodID. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-BucketedSortedTables

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try putting large table i.e Table A at the last, or stream table A to improve performance. You can try following query to stream table.

`select /*+STREAMTABLE(a)*/ a.* from TableA a inner join TableB b on a.prodID=b.prodID;`

Please refer [Tips using joins in hive](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2012/12/05/tip-using-joins-in-hive/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Chetna, STREAMTABLE concept is too old, isn't it? Because in recent versions these settings were enabled by default and the execution engine automatically decides which table to stream based on the size parameters set already.